# How to monitor a network device which is on it's own local network attached to a publicly reachable machine

Tags: mac-osx, monitoring, mac-osx-server, snmp

I would like to monitor a network device (a disarray) which is attached to a server with its own local network (10.0.0.x). The server is reachable from another private space (172.16.x.x).

I can do snmpwalk between my monitoring server and the machine in question. But I would also like to monitor the disk array attached to  the server in question.

Some sort of SNMP proxying or NATing comes to mind. So this could be a question on how to enable NAT (which would allow udp) on MacOS

Thanks

Comment: SSH port forwarding might get you going really easily here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a mac... just enable routing traffic between the two networks.  You can do this by enabling [packet-forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/114175/how-to-enable-packet-forwarding-in-mac-os-x).

Basically, this will make your mac into a simple ip router.  You may want to enable firewall rules to limit traffic to/from/through your mac tho.  Keep in mind, unless your "outside" machine (the one doing the snmpwalk) is using your mac as a router, you'll need to manually add a route to the 10. network using your mac as the gateway.  i.e.

```
route add --net 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 gw 172.16.mac.ip
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom OID in the SNMP config on the server which will execute the required snmpwalk commands.  Your monitoring server would then query these OIDs on the server, which would then query the disk array, and pass the results back.  Kind of a hack, but no worse then setting up routing on the server.

Comment: it has the implication that then I have to make my monitoring system understand the OID. Both the server and diskarray have physical disks (RAID) and they have OIDs for monitoring disk related things. Routing is probably a better choice.